# Regular expression to change lang in url path to be subdomain

Tags: php, regex

I am learning regex. I have a very simple question:

I have a long string of content in php.I would like to convert all places where it says:

```
http://www.example.com/en/rest-of-url
```

to

```
http://en.example.com/rest-of-url
```

Could somebody help me with this? I think I use preg_replace for this?

Bonus: If you have a link to a good site which explains how to do the simplest things like this in regex, please post it. Every regex resource I look at gets very complicated very fast (even the Wikipedia article).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP:

```
$search = '~http://www.example.com/([^/]+)/(.+)~';
$replace = 'http://$1.example.com/$2';
$new = preg_replace( $search, $replace, $original );
```

Answer (score 2):

http://regexlib.com/

has a nice regular expression cheat sheet and tester

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

```
preg_replace($regex, $replaceWith, $subject);
```

$subject is the original text.  $regex should be:

```
'@http://([^\.]*)\.example\.com/en/(.*)@'
```

$replaceWith should be:

```
'http://$1.example.com/$2'
```

**EDITED**: In my orignial answer, I had missed the fact that you wanted to capture part of the domain name.

Comment: You should use a different character for the delimiter instead of `/`, it makes the regex easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This will work with any domainname:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/en/rest-of-url';

echo preg_replace('%www(\..*?/)(\w+)/%', '\2\1', $url);
```

gives:

```
http://en.example.com/rest-of-url
```

Reference: [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can learn about basic regex, however for your simple question, there's no need for regex.

```
$str="http://www.example.com/en/rest-of-url";
$s = explode("/",$str);
unset( $s[3]);
print_r( implode("/",$s) ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great site for Regex Tutorials

http://www.regular-expressions.info/
[Regex Tutor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)